# javascript setting width dimensions changes element location

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to adjust the width of a `div` that is centred using JavaScript when a menu button is clicked, but when I do the width changes ok but it sets the element about 20px downwards too. This created a large empty gap above `contentSectionLeftSide`.

Here's what I've got:

```
 function setButtonH(e){

    var item = e;
    var items = ["menu_item1","menu_item2","menu_item3","menu_item4"];

    if(e==items[1])
    {
        document.getElementById("contentSectionLeftSide").style.width="600px";
        document.getElementById("contentSectionRightSide").style.width="300px";
        document.getElementById("contentSectionLeftSide").style.height="500px";
        document.getElementById("contentSectionRightSide").style.height="500px";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("contentSectionLeftSide").style.width="45%";
        document.getElementById("contentSectionRightSide").style.width="45%";
        document.getElementById("contentSectionLeftSide").style.height="500px";
        document.getElementById("contentSectionRightSide").style.height="500px";
     }
  }
```

HTML

```
 <nav id="menu_item">


        <div id="menu_item1" onclick="setButtonH('menu_item1'), menuGo(1)">

                Home

        </div>


        <div id="menu_item2" onclick="setButtonH('menu_item2'), menuGo(2)">

                Interests

        </div>

        <div id="menu_item3" onclick="setButtonH('menu_item3'), menuGo(3)">

                Creations

        </div>


        <div id="menu_item4" onclick="setButtonH('menu_item4'), menuGo(4)">

                Bio

        </div>

    </nav>



 #contentSectionLeftSide{

    padding:10px;
margin-bottom:4px;
background:#EFEFEF;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;  
display:inline-block;
 }
 #contentSectionRightSide{
padding:10px;
margin-bottom:4px;
background:#EFEFEF;
-webkit-border-radius:5px;  
display:inline-block;
}
```

Comment: Any HTML to go with this?

Comment: Where are the `contentSectionLeftSide` and `contentSectionRightSide` elements? And is there any other CSS that's associated with this HTML? Like from an external style sheet?

Comment: Here is the CSS. really confused now :(

Comment: The problem seems to occur when I add text to the div element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have a handle on the situation now, and recreating your code locally I did notice a small gap above the left content section.

The problem is that because your `div`s' content are (probably) resulting in different `div` heights, the `display: inline-block` CSS declaration is causing them to be vertically aligned to each other at the bottom baseline, so all you need to do is tell the CSS to align them vertically to the top.

I constructed the left- and right-hand side content areas like this, below the HTML you provided:

```
<nav id="menu_item">
    <div id="menu_item1" onclick="setButtonH('menu_item1')">Home</div>
    <div id="menu_item2" onclick="setButtonH('menu_item2')">Interests</div>
    <div id="menu_item3" onclick="setButtonH('menu_item3')">Creations</div>
    <div id="menu_item4" onclick="setButtonH('menu_item4')">Bio</div>
</nav>

<div id="contentSectionLeftSide">Left side content!</div>
<div id="contentSectionRightSide">
    Right side content!<br />
    There's a little more content in here!
</div>
```

I also removed the `menuGo(#)` function from the `onClick`'s, as I didn't know where that functionality went. Side note: be careful here, as in your code above it reads (for example):

```
onclick="setButtonH('menu_item2'), menuGo(2)"
```

Where it should be:

```
onclick="setButtonH('menu_item2'); menuGo(2)"
```

Which could yield problems down the line.

However, back to the solution, all you need to do is add the line `vertical-align: top;` to each of your content areas' style declarations, and they'll be aligned to the top, effectively:

```
#contentSectionLeftSide {
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    background:#EFEFEF;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;  
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* extra CSS... */
}

#contentSectionRightSide {
    padding:10px;
    margin-bottom:4px;
    background:#EFEFEF;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;  
    display:inline-block;
    vertical-align: top; /* extra CSS... */
}
```

[Here's a working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/GhNQ2/) for you to see it in action. Hope this helps, good luck and keep coding! :)

Comment: Wahhooo! you fixed it. You truly are a king of kings!

Comment: Haahaha! Or just an obsessive insomniac ;)